# How to move place order button to next page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to move the place order button of payment section to next part. How can i do it. [image]

Here the continue to paypal button need to go on summary page.

Comment: how did you convert this into 5 steps would you please share your code here ?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-checkout-step-magento-2.html

Comment: yes i know how to create new checkout steps but how to show products in cart and how to move shipping methods in next step ?

Comment: checkout_index_index.xml file. Moving things goes here.